# Widget gesture actions don't work for the widgets stacked over Htmlview in flutter web

Tags: flutter-web

I am stacking some widgets over HtmlView in FlutterWeb but found that none of the actions work for the widgets placed on HtmlView. The HtmlView consumes all the actions.  According to Flutter documentation platform view should only be getting events if none of the other widgets claim them.

Please see the min repro code below. I have tried placing ModalBottomSheet, SnackBar and Flatbutton over HtmlView showing youTube video and Google maps. None of those worked.

```
// Copyright 2018 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter_web_ui/ui.dart' as ui;
import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new Center(child: new Directionality( textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,child:HtmlExample())));
}

class HtmlExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HtmlExampleState createState() => new _HtmlExampleState();
}

class _HtmlExampleState extends State<HtmlExample> {
int count;
  @override
  void initState() {
    count = 0;
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        'hello-world-html',
            (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
          ..width = '640'
          ..height = '360'
          ..src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/IyFZznAk69U'
          ..style.border = 'none');
    super.initState();
    // We use 3600 milliseconds instead of 1800 milliseconds because 0.0 -> 1.0
    // represents an entire turn of the square whereas in the other examples
    // we used 0.0 -> math.pi, which is only half a turn.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      child:  HtmlView(viewType: 'hello-world-html')), //Text("Count = $count")),
      Text("Count = $count"),
      Column (children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(child: Text("Count"), color: Colors.red, onPressed: () => setState((){count++;})),
        Text("Count = $count"),
      ],)
    ],);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: I experienced the same issue. My solution was to modify the UI so that the flutter widgets weren't placed ontop of the htmlview - i realize that won't work for everyone.

Comment: They are fixing a bunch of platformview bugs https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/commits/master - you might be able to switch to the master branch and see if you have different results. I haven't read through all the commits.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the UI as well quite a bit to work around but also filed https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40058 which is still open.